# Finding oldest date in column with separated data

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a function that will search through a range and find the oldest date (the oldest date is in last row with data). My range is structured as following and I won't be able to change this structure:

```
Year Month Day
yyyy mm dd
```

So the year month and day are seperated in three different columns.

My code is as following:

```
Function OLDEST(yearrng As Range) As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim year, month, day As String

lastrow = Range(yearrng).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
year = Range("I" & lastrow).value
month = year.Offset(0, 1).value
day = year.Offset(0, 2).value

OLDEST = year & month & day

End Function
```

The yearrng is the same range which the years are displayed.

The problem is that this function is *not* working and is returning "value error"...

I hope you understood my question.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but what *is* your question?

Comment: Why my function is not working. 
Edit: Updated my post

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *not working*? If you get an error: Which line throws an error and what is the error message? If  the result is not what you expect - what is the result? Have you debugged the code to check where it fails?

Comment: My cell with the function is displaying "Value Error". I think it is the "lastrow =..." line which gives the error message. But as it is a function it won't let me debug the code, hence i don't know exactly where it is wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You could avoid using a function. Just use a formula like: =CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("I"&COUNTA(K:K)),INDIRECT("J"&COUNTA(K:K)),INDIRECT("K"&COUNTA(K:K))). Especially since your function is wrong in many places.

Comment: It worked! Thank you JvdV.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-volatile worksheet function, you can try:

```
=DATE(LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($I:$I)>0),I:I),LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($I:$I)>0),J:J),LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($I:$I)>0),K:K))
```

where `I` is the column to test for which is the "bottom" row, and `I`, `J`, and `K` are the columns with the relevant date parts.